# Windows SBS 08 domain controller is missing \\Localhost\NETLOGON share

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs-2008, netlogon

One and only working logon server in the domain. When I run DCDIAG, it returns:

> Starting test: NetLogons
>            * Network Logons Privileges Check
>            Unable to connect to the NETLOGON share! (\SBS08-DC\netlogon)
>            [SBS08-DC] An net use or LsaPolicy operation failed with error
>            1203,
>            The network path was either typed incorrectly, does not exist, or the network provider is not currently available. Please try
>   retyping the path or contact your network
>   administrator........................... SBS08-DC failed test
>   NetLogons

There are no recent backups that contain the NETLOGON folder that I can find, and this is the only working logon server. I have tried to recreate the NETLOGON folder by setting registry key `HKEY_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters` SysVolReady=1, SysVolReady0, then rebooting, but it did not work.

As I said, the other DC does not work as a logon server, so I cannot replicate NETLOGON from it (it too does not have one). Lastly, I cannot yet move FSMO's away from the SBS 08 DC since it also run Exchange. What are my options here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did and it seems to have worked, but please tell me if this was not the best route:

- On the only working logon server (SBS 08), C:\Windows\Sysvol\Domain\Scripts folder did not exist. As such, the NETLOGON subfolder also did not exist.
- I google'd to find [what the Share and NTFS permissions of NETLOGON should be.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319808/sysvol-junction-inherits-ntfs-permissions-from-the-drive-root)
- I stopped the File Replication Service on SBS 08 DC.
- I manually created a NETLOGON in the correct location on the SBS 08 DC, then made sure Share and NTFS permissions were set correctly.
- I restarted the File Replication Service on SBS 08 DC and sure enough, it replicated the Scripts\NETLOGON out to both Svr 2012 R2 DC2 and DC3.
- However, it did not create them as shares, so I manually set \%LogonServer%\NETLOGON to be shared with read rights for everyone on Sv2 2012R2 DC2 and DC3.
- I then re-ran DCDIAG on all three DC's and all three passed!
- I shutdown SBS 08 DC and sure enough, Svr 2012R2 DC2 logged in 3 test client PC's!